# Problem with Images out of canvas Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, canvas

I have a 900x900 pixel canvas . I placed a png in a new layer . The width of the png image overflows the canvas . Ofcourse the overflow of the image is hidden because it is out of the canvas , but i don't want that to happen . I just want the png image to fit the canvas without showing the overflow when i select the layer . How can i do it ?

[image: canvasproblem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Select > Select All`
2. `Image > Crop`

This will delete anything outside the document boundaries **which is pixel based**. That means it will *not* trim away smart objects or vector layers. There's no simple way to trim smart objects and vector layers to match the document size.